# htaccess require host domain not working correctly

Tags: json, ajax, .htaccess

I have a folder full of folders with json files. I want to restrict AJAX requests to these files to certain domains.

I made an htaccess file to restrict this but it isn't work. My htaccess is as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "\.json$">
    <RequireAny>
        Require host thedomain.com
        Require host thehurts.com
    </RequireAny>
</FilesMatch>
```

This is blocking everyone, including myself.

I read that `Require local` gives myself access but that didn't work when I added it.

if I add `Require all granted` I have access and can AJAX to the files from other domains but that also gives access to everyone on the internet, which is what I don't want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to limit it from the source.

You should be able to set environment variables for referring domains and then include that in the rule. Then you can do by IP address to limit it coming from the server or your IP address also.

```
    SetEnvIf Referer "example\.com" localreferer
    SetEnvIf Referer "example2\.com" localreferer2

    <FilesMatch "\.json$">
        Require env localreferer
        Require env localreferer2
        Require ip x.x.x.x #your ip address
        Require ip 127.0.0.1 #localhost
        Requite ip x.x.x.x #replace with your local server IP. 
    </FilesMatch>
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Ok let me know how it goes. Note, the refer has to be the exact hostname its coming from for example. www.example.com or example.com. which ever you are using from the other domain.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much! I've literally been working on this all day.

Comment: Why do we need to limit it to an environment variable? I'm curious on why it would just not let us do Require host hostname. Looking at the docs it does not talk about doing any env variables.